# Can apps purchased for iPad be downloaded on MacBook

Tags: ipad, applications, macbook-pro

I purchased the iA Writer app for my iPad. Can I download it free on my MacBook?

Thanks.

Comment: You can download the iOS app using iTunes on your MacBook.  But it will not run in Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks. I see the same-named app for sale in the store when I go there from my MacBook. I was hoping that because I bought their product on one platform I could get it for free on another platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it, for the purposes of backup/syncing etc with iOS devices via iTunes, but it is not an OS X application so it will not run.  Some companies release software for both platforms, often with the same name/version number/price point, but they are separate applications, and when you buy you are purchasing on a platform specific basis, so even if you own iA Writer (or Byword, or any other cross platform app) you only own it on the platform for which it was purchased.

Answer (score 0):

Some software companies do have such a policy, but Apple certainly does not require it.  So inquire from the producers of that app.

Comment: Although Apple does not allow offers like tis on their AppStores - the cost must be the same for all purchasers. They can off this from the producers own site

Comment: I believe I saw one app ... when you buy the OS X app, you also get unlock codes for the "free trial" version of the iOS app and their other mobile versions.